# Hashing and GetString/GetBytes issue

Tags: c#, .net, encryption, hash, salt

I have the below code to hash/store/retrieve data for passwords but my first unit test and it fails.

I beleive its the Encoding causing the problem because when GetBytes is called it returns `byte[38]`, `byte[36]` when it should be 20 I think.

I have to convert to string as I'm storing it in a database.

Any ideas? Thanks

```
[Fact]
public void EncryptDecryptPasswordShouldMatch()
{
    string password = "password";
    string passwordKey = string.Empty;
    string passwordSalt = string.Empty;

    Helpers.CreatePasswordHash(password, out passwordSalt, out passwordKey);

    Assert.True(Helpers.PasswordsMatch(passwordSalt, passwordKey, password));

}


public static bool PasswordsMatch(string passwordSalt, string passwordKey, string password)
{
    byte[] salt = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(passwordSalt);
    byte[] key = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(passwordKey);

    using (var deriveBytes = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(password, salt))
    {
        byte[] newKey = deriveBytes.GetBytes(20);  // derive a 20-byte key

        if (!newKey.SequenceEqual(key))
            return false;
    }

    return true;
}

public static void CreatePasswordHash(string password, out string passwordSalt, out string passwordKey)
{
    // specify that we want to randomly generate a 20-byte salt
    using (var deriveBytes = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(password, 20))
    {
        byte[] salt = deriveBytes.Salt;
        byte[] key = deriveBytes.GetBytes(20);  // derive a 20-byte key

        passwordSalt = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(salt);
        passwordKey = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(key);
    }
}
```

Comment: Use Base64 to encode binary values to string, it can deal with arbitrary byte sequences. UTF-8 is for transforming between unicode text and bytes and not every valid sequence of bytes is valid for UTF-8.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use Base64 to encode binary values to string, it can deal with arbitrary byte sequences. UTF-8 is for transforming between unicode text and bytes and not every valid sequence of bytes is valid for UTF-8. Use Utf-8 to turn the password(which is text) to bytes, but use Base64 for salt and hash.

[`Convert.ToBase64String`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.convert.tobase64string.aspx) and [`Convert.FromBase64String`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.convert.frombase64string.aspx) should do the trick.

---

Some additional notes:

- Your terminology is really weird, don't call the hash `key`, call it `hash`.
- I'd concatenate the hash and salt in your `CreatePasswordHash` function, so the caller doesn't have to bother with having two separate values.

  Something like `return Base64Encode(salt)+"$"+Base64Encode(hash)` then use `string.Split` in the verification function.
- It's recommended to use a constant time comparison to verify, but it seems unlikely your timing side-channel can actually be exploited.
- Your iteration count is pretty low. I recommend increasing it to 10000.

Comment: Can you reliably split on $ - what if that character is in there

Comment: @Jon Both hash and salt are the output of a Base64 encoder. Base64 never produces `$`, so there will only be that single `$` which works as separator.

Comment: @Jon: Then **hire a crypto professional**. It is *so easy* to get this stuff wrong and build an insecure system. I know enough about password systems to know that I'm not competent to do a good job, so I don't try.

Comment: @EricLippert Since password hashing is a really common problem, it would have been nice if Microsoft had hired the cryptographer to add class to the BCL that's easy to use and secure. Even *php* got it right.

Answer (score 3):

Modify your code to use the `Convert.FromBase64String` method:

```
byte[] salt = Convert.FromBase64String(passwordSalt);
byte[] key = Convert.FromBase64String(passwordKey);
```

Modify your code to use the `Convert.ToBase64String` method:

```
passwordSalt = Convert.ToBase64String(salt);
passwordKey = Convert.ToBase64String(key);
```

Answer (score 1):

[UTF8](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8) is not a way to turn any random bytes into a string. It is for encoding text; not just any bytes are valid UTF8 encoded values.  You could use Base64 [to](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dhx0d524.aspx) and [from](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.convert.frombase64string.aspx) conversions. Note that base64-encoded strings will take up ~4/3 times the characters of the raw bytes.  Here's an example:

```
byte[] salt = deriveBytes.Salt;
byte[] key = deriveBytes.GetBytes(20);  // derive a 20-byte key

passwordSalt = Convert.ToBase64String(salt);
passwordKey = Convert.ToBase64String(key);
```

And later:

```
byte[] salt = Convert.FromBase64String(passwordSalt);
byte[] key = Convert.FromBase64String(passwordKey);
```